# Nearby connections 2.0 simple files exchange app

Tags: google-play-services, google-nearby

I'm trying to write simple android file exchange application, mostly using snippets from https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/android/exchange-data and Walkietalkie app.

But I'm stuck on transferring File payload second sendPayload, onPayloadTransferUpdate called only on sending side. Discovering, advertising, connecting to the endpoint, everything works fine. The sender is "sending", but Reciever gets only string message with id and filename and waits (onPayloadTransferUpdate called only 2 times for the first sendPayload) and then nothing, disconnects after sender finished transferring.

```
public void sendFile(String uri) {
    File file = new File(uri);
    if (file.exists() && mEstablishedConnections.values().size() > 0) {
        for (Endpoint endpoint : mEstablishedConnections.values()) {
            try {
                // Open the ParcelFileDescriptor for this URI with read access.
                ParcelFileDescriptor pfd = getContentResolver().openFileDescriptor(Uri.fromFile(file), "r");

                Payload filePayload = Payload.fromFile(pfd);

                // Construct a simple message mapping the ID of the file payload to the desired filename.
                String payloadFilenameMessage = filePayload.getId() + ":" + Uri.fromFile(file).getLastPathSegment();

                // Send this message as a bytes payload.
                Nearby.Connections.sendPayload(mGoogleApiClient,
                        endpoint.getId(),
                        Payload.fromBytes(payloadFilenameMessage.getBytes("UTF-8")));

                // Finally, send the file payload.
                Nearby.Connections.sendPayload(mGoogleApiClient,
                        endpoint.getId(),
                        filePayload);


            } catch (FileNotFoundException | UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "sendFile: EstablishedConnections == 0");
    }
}

private final PayloadCallback mPayloadCallback = new PayloadCallback() {

    @Override
    public void onPayloadReceived(String endpointId, Payload payload) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onPayloadReceived(endpointId=%s, payload=%s)", endpointId, payload));

        try {
            if (payload.getType() == Payload.Type.BYTES) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onPayloadReceived: Payload.Type.BYTES");
                String payloadFilenameMessage = new String(payload.asBytes(), "UTF-8");
                Log.d(TAG, "onPayloadReceived: BYTES " + payloadFilenameMessage);
                addPayloadFilename(payloadFilenameMessage);
            } else if (payload.getType() == Payload.Type.FILE) {
                // Add this to our tracking map, so that we can retrieve the payload later.
                incomingFilePayloads.put(payload.getId(), payload);

                Log.d(TAG, "onPayloadReceived: Payload.Type.FILE");
            } else if (payload.getType() == Payload.Type.STREAM) {
                //payload.asStream().asInputStream()
                Log.d(TAG, "onPayloadReceived: Payload.Type.STREAM");
            }
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPayloadTransferUpdate(String endpointId, PayloadTransferUpdate update) {
        Log.d(TAG, String.format("onPayloadTransferUpdate(endpointId=%s, update=%s)",
                endpointId, update));

        switch(update.getStatus()) {
            case PayloadTransferUpdate.Status.IN_PROGRESS:
                break;
            case PayloadTransferUpdate.Status.SUCCESS:
                Log.d(TAG, "onPayloadTransferUpdate: SUCCESS");
                Payload payload = incomingFilePayloads.remove(update.getPayloadId());
                 if (payload != null && payload.getType() == Payload.Type.FILE) {
                    // Retrieve the filename that was received in a bytes payload.
                    String newFilename = filePayloadFilenames.remove(update.getPayloadId());
                    java.io.File payloadFile = payload.asFile().asJavaFile();

                    // Rename the file.
                    payloadFile.renameTo(new File(payloadFile.getParentFile(), newFilename));

                }

                break;
            case PayloadTransferUpdate.Status.FAILURE:
                Log.d(TAG, "onPayloadTransferUpdate: FAILURE");
                break;
        }
    }
};
```

Is there a working example apart from google sample walkietalkie?

Sender

> D/ShareService: sendFile: filename message -7668342386822656500:a73ecba18dc6c8506ed89c1ed47c9948.mp4
>
> D/ShareService: onPayloadTransferUpdate(endpointId=osUc, update=com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.PayloadTransferUpdate@e16fc0a8)
>   D/ShareService: onPayloadTransferUpdate: 57
>   D/ShareService: onPayloadTransferUpdate: 1048576
>   D/DiscoveryActivity: onNext: ShareState{state='Sending ', stateCode=800}
>   D/ShareService: onPayloadTransferUpdate(endpointId=osUc, update=com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.PayloadTransferUpdate@813731ce)
>   D/ShareService: onPayloadTransferUpdate: 1055744
>   D/DiscoveryActivity: onNext: ShareState{state='Sending ', stateCode=800}
>   D/ShareService: onPayloadTransferUpdate(endpointId=osUc, update=com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.PayloadTransferUpdate@81372a4c)
>   11-01 07:35:20.790  D/ShareService: onPayloadTransferUpdate: SUCCESS
>   11-01 07:35:41.587  D/ShareService: disconnectedFromEndpoint(endpoint=Endpoint{id=osUc, name=87389})
>   11-01 07:35:41.587  D/ShareService: onEndpointDisconnected

Reciever

> D/ShareService: onConnectionResponse(endpointId=ABVq, result=com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.ConnectionResolution@9edd5e3)
>   D/ShareService: connectedToEndpoint(endpoint=Endpoint{id=ABVq, name=08043})
>   D/ShareService: onEndpointConnected
>   D/ShareService: stopDiscovering
>   D/ShareService: stopAdvertising
>
> D/ShareService: onPayloadReceived(endpointId=ABVq, payload=com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.Payload@516155e)
>   D/ShareService: onPayloadReceived: Payload.Type.BYTES
>   D/ShareService: onPayloadReceived: BYTES -7668342386822656500:a73ecba18dc6c8506ed89c1ed47c9948.mp4
>   D/ShareService: onPayloadTransferUpdate(endpointId=ABVq, update=com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.PayloadTransferUpdate@ba6f47ac)
>   D/ShareService: onPayloadTransferUpdate: 57
>   D/ShareService: onPayloadTransferUpdate(endpointId=ABVq, update=com.google.android.gms.nearby.connection.PayloadTransferUpdate@ba6f402a)
>   11-01 08:10:52.525 D/ShareService: onPayloadTransferUpdate: SUCCESS
>   11-01 08:11:12.355 D/ShareService: disconnectedFromEndpoint(endpoint=Endpoint{id=ABVq,name=08043})
>   D/ShareService: onEndpointDisconnected

onPayloadTransferUpdate: SUCCESS for first string transfer

delay

```
Payload bytePayload = outgoingPayloads.remove(update.getPayloadId());
                            if (bytePayload != null && bytePayload.getType() == Payload.Type.BYTES) {
                                if (endpnt != null && filePayload != null) {
                                    try {
                                        Thread.sleep(10000);
                                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }
                                    Nearby.Connections.sendPayload(mGoogleApiClient,
                                            endpnt.getId(),
                                            filePayload);
                                }
                            }
```

file:///data/data/com.package.name/files/folder/a73ecba18dc6c8506ed89c1ed47c9948.mp4

sources https://github.com/salexwm/FilesExchange

Answer (score 2):

I can provide a working example if you need one, but you almost have it. Some pointers:

1. Send the FILE payload only after the BYTE header has fully sent, in onPayloadTransferUpdate(SUCCESS). Order isn't guaranteed for payloads of different types.
2. Don't disconnect until you get onPayloadTransferUpdate(SUCCESS) for the FILE payload. If you disconnect during transmission, it won't fully send.
3. You should be doing Uri.parse(uri), not Uri.fromFile(new File(uri)).

Comment: Thx for the answer, I updated 1st post with logcat output. 1. It always sends string with id:filename first in may case and after file payload. 2. It disconnected automatically after 20s 3. if i use  Uri.parse it return provider not found

Comment: 1. The code in your question is not waiting for the BYTE payload to be received by the other side. It's sending the BYTE payload and the FILE payload at the same time. You'll need to fully send the BYTE payload, wait for onPayloadTransferUpdate(SUCCESS), and then send the FILE payload. 2. That should be fine. 3. What's your "String uri" look like? If it looks like "file://sdcard/foo.pdf", then Uri.parse should work. If it looks like "sdcard/foo.pdf", then it's not a uri, it's a file path, and your code is correct (but your variable is misnamed).

Comment: Feel free to link to a Github page (or something similar), and I can leave more detailed comments on the code itself. Then we can update this StackOverflow post with a nice solution.

Comment: Double-checked the file yes it starts with file:// changed to content:// (using fileprovider) - same result, moved sender sendPayload (FILE) to onPayloadTransferUpdate (after BYTE) even added 10s thread sleep(just to test) so it 100% starts after reciever got the BYTE part (id:filename) - same result, i'm definitely missing something :(

Comment: uploaded sources https://github.com/salexwm/FilesExchange, have to strip all rxjava, dagger injects

Comment: Sorry, I've gotten a bit bogged down in work. I'll try and take a look by end of this week.